# In IE lightbox doesn't show if a synchronous ajax request is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I've got the following code that shows a lightbox 'please wait' box, then does a synchronous ajax request which removes the lightbox when it finishes.  Works fine everywhere else, but in IE, the lightbox doesn't show.  The Ajax request works fine, but it just seems to ignore the lightbox.

The `showLightbox` function just does that, show a modal lightbox with the passed in text.

```
showLightbox("Please Wait");

$.ajax({
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: checkValidUrl,
    data: submitData,
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        valid = false;
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        valid=true;
    },
    complete: function(request, textStatus) {
        hideLightbox();
    }
});
```

If I make the ajax requst async it works fine, but I need it to be synchronous because this is a validation method.

**Update**: Also, if I wrap the whole ajax request in a setTimeout it also works in IE, but that is asynchronous too

**Update 2**: I just replaced the lightbox with a simple div and did a jQuery .show() on beforeSend and .hide() on complete, and it didn't show that either, so it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the lightbox.  If I whack an `alert()` immediately after `showLightbox()` it does show the lightbox

Comment: sounds like a css problem. post ur markup and css

Comment: How can this be a CSS issue if it works on an async request?

Comment: If you "need it to be synchronous", you're doing it wrong. What happens to the user whose network connection drops as they're filling out your form? You just locked up their browser, and the only way out is to kill the process... along with any other tabs they had open. There is *never* a good reason to make a synchronous call within the browser. That capability was only included in Microsoft's original XHR implementation as it was an ActiveX control that could be used in many contexts other than as part of the browser, in some of which synchronous requests might be acceptable.

Comment: It doesn't lock the browser (except in IE 6 sometimes because it's useless) it just makes the site have a modal lightbox over it.  They can close that tab at any time.

Comment: everyone should have a squiz at this article: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Snippets:_Synchronous_AJAX - at the bottom is a synchronous request with 10 second delay. In Firefox (3.5.2) it looks like the browser tabs still stay un-frozen, but the cursor stays as a pointer (a hand) and you can't scroll. Internet Explorer (7) completely chokes though and the browser is completely unusable until the request completes. As it says in the article, there are a few situations (onunload events) where SJAX is useful, but AJAX is what you want for 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that IE either is too busy doing the request to show the lightbox or that it thinks it's supposed to stop to do the request. Try adding the showLightbox() function to the $.ajax function itself, to the `beforeSend` option.

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: checkValidUrl,
    data: submitData,
    beforeSend: showLightbox(),
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        valid = false;
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        valid=true;
    },
    complete: function(request, textStatus) {
        hideLightbox();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried some dummy function? Have the beforeSend turn the body background yellow, and then green on complete. You need to determine if the issue is with the lightbox plugin or if IE simply doesn't want to do anything other than make the request.

Comment: Yeah, it does call those sort of methods.  It's only the dynamic show/hide of elements that seems to be the problem.  I've run into this before, not using a lightbox, but just showing a hidden div before a synchronous request, so I don't think it's the lightbox itself

Comment: I just replaced the lightbox with a simple div and did a jQuery .show() on beforeSend and .hide() on complete, and it didn't show that either

Comment: This may be grasping a bit, but what about if you use `$.ajaxSetup` for the before, during, after functions, and a `$.get` for the ajax call. Obviously IE doesn't want to do DOM mods on sync requests, so your next best option is to trick it somehow. Maybe have the ajax request as part of the showLightbox function?

Comment: This may be a total cop-out, as it wouldn't explain the issue, but does any non-"jiggly" stall in the script fix the issue? Instead of throwing an alert, could you just declare a variable or have the script do some math?

Comment: You could even make it slightly less hacky if you can make it throw two lightboxes. The first one says "If you can read this, you're on IE" the second "Please Wait". :p

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax call, you need to call the lightbox functionality again. I used Lytebox, so it may be different for you.

```
$j.post("kitchen.php", $j("#post_form").serialize(),function(result) {
    //xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_test.php",true);
    //xmlhttp.send();
    $j('#grab_kitchen').attr({'disabled' : 'false'});
    $j('#grab_kitchen').removeAttr('disabled');
    $j('#Output').fadeIn(500);
    $j('#Output').html(result);
    $j("body").css("cursor", "auto");

    // add there your lytebox function to work
    initLytebox();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This smells funny.

Firstly, I can't think of any good reason for using a synchronous request -- doing so locks the user's browser until the response is returned. It's a terrible user experience which would make most users think your website is killing their browser.

Secondly, you say you're doing this for validation? Any user who is malicious enough to try to alter a form while they wait for the asynchronous response would also be smart enough to just change your "async: false" to "async: true". Remember that all validation on the client side is *only* there for the benefit of the user, and all proper validation should be done server-side. I don't see why you'd need to do things this way.

Comment: Yes it locks, that's what the please wait lightbox is for. Yes we do server side validation, but we want to be able to tell the user at the top of the form that this data is wrong, before they get to the end and have to go back and start again.  JS validation is always done for user convienience, not data security

Comment: so if you've got a lightbox over the page, then why not just use asynchronous requests?

Comment: Because it's not the user I'm needing to block, it's the function return, this is inside a validation method using the jQuery validate plugin.  I need to know what the return status of the ajax request is before I return from the function

Comment: Yeah, I still don't think you're doing it right. You should be using callbacks to handle the response from AJAX, not synchronous requests.

Comment: How can you use callbacks in the middle of a validate function?

Comment: step 1, user enters data, step 2, you send the data to the server for validation, step 3, server responds with some data and your callback function displays a tick or a cross depending if it worked.

Comment: The validation call is a blocking event, they're clicking on a box that will close an accordian interface and proceed the user forward.  It *has* to wait and check first

Comment: In that case, I think depending on the validation framework is actually your problem. Why not intercept the "clicking on a box" and run a normal async ajax call instead of whatever it's doing now? Then if the return value indicates a success, your callback can trigger the action that the click currently triggers (closing the accordion interface and proceed the user forward).

Comment: @Glenn: Ok, you can still block the user until the request completes **without** freezing their browser. A simple lightbox overlay, like you already have, would be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should show the lightbox, and then do a setTimeout before you actually begin the synchronous request. I suspect that IE doesn't render your DOM changes until it gets control back from your JS function, and that doesn't happen until after the ajax request, and the box is hidden again. Give it a chance to render the lightbox, and then start your ajax request.

```
showLightbox("Please Wait");

setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: checkValidUrl,
        data: submitData,
        error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            valid = false;
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            valid=true;
        },
        complete: function(request, textStatus) {
            hideLightbox();
        }
    });
}, 100);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that makes the request asynchronous, I need it to wait until the ajax request comes back.

Comment: How does that make the request asynchronous? The user would have a grand total of a tenth of a second to mess with things before the synchronous ajax call locked up the browser.

Comment: Personally, what I do in situations like this is cover the entire page with a grey div that has its opacity set to 1%. This prevents the user from clicking anything while I make an ordinary asynch ajax call, and remove the covering div in the callback. If the ajax call is likely to take a while, a "Please Wait" message along with preventing clicks goes a long way.

Comment: This isn't blocking the user, it's blocking the interface from progressing forward.  As I mentioned, the lightbox Please wait text is already blocking the user from doing anything, I need to make the JS wait for a response before it moves the user onto the next section

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact issue.

http://www.precisehomebuilders.com/kitchen-remodeling

There is a button at the bottom of the page that grabs more photo galleries, which works.

Here's the thing: if I do a "save as" after the ajax call and reload it, then it totally works.  There's just something about grabbing lightbox items through ajax.